# How to grab the head section of a website using the curl and grep command?

Tags: text-processing, grep, curl, html

I'm taking my Linux+ midterm and I'm stuck on a question where I'm supposed to copy the head section including the tags and output it to a file. My midterm is due on the 5th so it would really help if someone showed me the correct code to use when greping for the head section and tags. I tried:  `curl www.hackthissite.org: grep "<head> > ~/data/public/myfirstname\ mylastname/head.txt` but all it would say when I cat the file is`<head>`, doesn't include the head section or  tag. So what should I type to get the correct output to the file?

Comment: Required reading... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/525010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit more complex than what you're trying to do.

First, there are some syntax issues on your command. This `curl www.hackthissite.org: grep "<head> > ~/data/public/myfirstname\ mylastname/head.txt` should be:

`curl www.hackthissite.org | grep "<head>" > ~/data/public/myfirstname\ mylastname/head.txt`

But even though it wouldn't do what you want, because you're only greping the head opening tag, but not what comes in between it and the closing tag.

I came up with this:

```
curl www.hackthissite.org > TEMPORARYFILE.txt; grep -A $(($(grep -n "</head>" TEMPORARYFILE.txt | cut -d: -f1) - $(grep -n "<head>" TEMPORARYFILE.txt | cut -d: -f1))) "<head>" TEMPORARYFILE.txt > ~/data/public/myfirstname\ mylastname/head.txt; rm TEMPORARYFILE.txt
```

So, by parts:

`grep -n "</head>" TEMPORARYFILE.txt | cut -d: -f1`

This will get the number of the line where the closing tag is. The same applies to `grep -n "<head>" TEMPORARYFILE.txt | cut -d: -f1`, but for the opening tag.

Then we have `$(($(grep -n "</head>" TEMPORARYFILE.txt | cut -d: -f1) - $(grep -n "<head>" TEMPORARYFILE.txt | cut -d: -f1)))`, which is supposed to calculate how many lines there are between the opening tag and the closing tag.

This is used with the `-A` option of `grep`, which gives us control of how many lines after the match we want printed. So it will search for the opening head tag and print all the lines between it and the closing tag.

Comment: It give me a syntax error for "-", says file.txt has no file or directory, ":" is an invalid argument for "--directories" and gives me a list of valid arguments, and it gives me different errors everytime I try to use your code.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I used a file to test the code (instead of downloading the page every time) and forgot to change it so it only used the output of `curl`. I'll fix it.

Comment: I fixed it. It should now create a temporary file on the directory you run it into with the contents of the `curl` request and delete it after it's done (so even though it's unlikely, be sure you run it in a folder that don't have a file named *TEMPORARYFILE.txt*).

Comment: It works for a few seconds, then errors out and says invalid arguments "-f1' for "--directories" valid arguments are read, recurse, and skip. Usage grep [OPTION]... PATTERN  [FILE]... Try grep --help for more information. bash: -; syntax error: operand expected (error token is "- "). That's the only error I get now.

Comment: I've fixed your code, -f1 is supposed to be -f 1, after that, it worked! Thanks so much for your help, I'm sure to get an A on my midterm now!

Comment: It worked here with -f1, maybe the `cut` version you have is different then mine? Also, the error you wrote on the other comment seemed to be related to `grep`, so maybe you forgot the pipe?

Answer (score 1):

Using gawk:

```
curl -s www.hackthissite.org | awk '/<\<head>/,/<\/head>/ {print}'
```